# lapply using iterator as parameter for function

Tags: r, parameters, iterator, data.table, lapply

I try solving a problem with lapply. Being a SAS-Programmer this way of thinking is quite new to me.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
```

I have a data.table like this

```
DT <- data.table(idnum= c(1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1003,1003,1003,1003),
             a_beg= c(16079, 16700, 17000, 16074, 17000, 16074, 17000, 18081, 19000),
             a_end= c(16500, 16850, 22000, 16900, 22000, 16950, 18000, 18950, 21000))
```

a_beg and a_end containing sas-date number (days since 1960-01-01)

This is my function years. I want to apply my function to the data.table object keeping only rows which interval overlaps study year

```
 years <- function(DT, year) {

 DT <- DT[lubridate::date('1960-01-01')+a_beg <= lubridate::ymd(paste(year, 1, 1, sep = "-"))
        & lubridate::date('1960-01-01')+a_end >= lubridate::ymd(paste(year, 12, 31, sep = "-")), ]
 DT
 }
```

Doing it without apply works just fine...

```
year2005 <- years(DT, 2005)
```

I want to do something like this...
stepping through study years
using bind_rows and pipe into data.table

```
 DT <- bind_rows(lapply(DT, 2004:2015, years())) %>% data.table()
```

I want to use the iterator as a parameter for the function, I don't know how.

Comment: What's the point of converting all the columns to date over and over again? Wouldn't t make sense to have `a_beg` and `a_end` in Date format already? Also why do you want to iterate? You need to count how many dates fall in each interval? If so, I would suggest using a join combined with `by = .EACHI`. Finally, you are mixing too many packages here. No need in lubrdate at all here. and data.table has `rbindlist` so need in dplyr neither.

Comment: Must be annoying to read the syntax of a beginner, so thanks for giving it a closer look anyway. Still learning R and struggle to get rid SAS-Thinking ;-)

Comment: Not so annoying actually. I'm just trying to understand what is the end result you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
years <- function(year, DTbl) {
    #data.table changes by reference so you do not want your subset to overwrite the original DT
    DTbl[lubridate::date('1960-01-01')+a_beg <= lubridate::ymd(paste(year, 1, 1, sep = "-"))
            & lubridate::date('1960-01-01')+a_end >= lubridate::ymd(paste(year, 12, 31, sep = "-")), ]    
}
bind_rows(lapply(2004:2015, years, DTbl=DT)) %>% data.table()
```

Or if we use more [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax, you can do a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s non-equi join as follows:

```
DT[, ':=' (
    a_beg = as.Date(a_beg, origin="1960-01-01"),
    a_end = as.Date(a_end, origin="1960-01-01")
)]

yearRanges <- data.table(beg=seq(as.Date("2004-01-01"), by="1 year", length.out=12), 
    end=seq(as.Date("2004-12-31"), by="1 year", length.out=12))

DT[yearRanges,
    .(YEAR=year(beg), idnum=x.idnum, a_beg=x.a_beg, a_end=x.a_end),
    on=.(a_beg <= beg, a_end >= end),
    allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Some of the data.table syntax is new to me and I will have a closer look at that today and see what it faster on a 8GB Dataset ;-)